# How to Create Bins/Buckets for a Measure in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a measure(not a calculated column) that calculates a ratio across two tables...(0-100%). The measure is essentially a score.

I need to create buckets for each persons score. I've seen solutions that use calc. columns, but not measures. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish by doing the following:

1. Create external unrelated table with the different bins.
2. Create Measure that calculated a count over the target table and measure using the bins as filter contect. It looked like this.

   ```
   bin test = 
   var currentBucket = SELECTEDVALUE(Buckets[Name])
   var currentBucketMin = SELECTEDVALUE(Buckets[Min])
   var currentBucketMax = SELECTEDVALUE(Buckets[Max])
       return
   CALCULATE(
   COUNTROWS('Team Member'),
   FILTER(
       VALUES('Team Member'[TeamMemberKeyInt]),
       var histUtil = [Utilization]
       return

           histUtil >= currentBucketMin && histUtil < currentBucketMax
       )
       )
   ```

Answer (score -1):

To establish an evaluation context, you need a persisted column in the dataset. A measure cannot yield the evaluation context - a measure is evaluated within an evaluation context.

If you want to create bins, you need something like this added as a calculated column in your persons table:

```
Score bins =
VAR _score = [Your measure]
RETURN
    SWITCH (
        TRUE(),
        _score > 90, "90-100",
        _score > 80, "80-90",
        _score > 60, "60-80",
        _score > 30, "30-60",
        "0-30"
    )
```

You can then use this column as the category designator for a bar chart, and use a simple `COUNTROWS` measure over your persons table to provide the count.